# Dns Server (edns)opt type of resource record

Tags: resources, dns, record

i want to request for an opt resource record message to dns server bind 9.

but i don't know the format and the server configration.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2671.txt this doc is the edns doc.

i create the message formatted following the doc,but it doesn't work. server tell me format error.

the req message:

```
Question Record:
QName:a6.debian.com
QType:0x41(OPT type)
QClass:0x01(Internet)
Additional Record:
Resource Name:0xc0,0x0c( pointer to QName)
Resource Type:0x41
ResourceClass:512(udp payload size)
TimeToLive:0x1EF0000(split to extent-code version and Z)
ResourceDataLength:0x08
Rdata:(OPTRdata):
    OptCode:0x4000
    OptLength:0x04
    OptData:0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A
```

What's wrong???Could you help me?

Answer (score 4):

There's no OPT type record. OPT is *pseudo*-record type. You can not query for it. You use OPT to pass some specific parameters to DNS server, like EDNS. Besides it can appear in "ADDITIONAL" section only

Comment: Thanks, i see. and do you know about NIMLOC TSIG TKEY NB type of resource record? i need to query for those type to dns server...

Comment: I think TKEY and NIMLOC are a regular RRs, while TKEY is somewhat  similar to OPT - it used in transmission and never appears in the DNS data (i.e. zone file) itself.

Comment: Anyway, why you need all those ?

Comment: i'm testing the dns parser, i must create query message to get every resource record from dns server...